# Using default Firefox profile in Watir Webdriver but switching off JavaScript

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium, webdriver, watir

I would like to use my default profile in firefox when watir-webdriver launches a friefox browser, but then I want to switch off javascript in that browser this way:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff, :profile => "default"
browser.profile['javascript.enabled']=false
```

The second reference doesn't work, because the "profile" is not a member of the browser object. How can I access it? Or any other method to switch off javascript either in the default profile or in the running firefox window? I want to do this programmatically, because at the end of my Ruby script I would like to switch it on again.

Comment: I have found how to do this with Selenium on this page [link](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/TipsAndTricks) but it doesn't work with watir-webdriver and Ruby.

Comment: finally I have found it:

`default_profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.from_name "default"

default_profile.native_events = true

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox, :profile => default_profile)`

Comment: I do not see where you have disabled javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would do it like this:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new  
profile['javascript.enabled'] = false  
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff, :profile => profile
```